# Group By and Sum of List[String] in scala

Tags: java, scala

I have a List[List[Int]] and I want to group by on A and sum of rest of value the inside List[Int]

```
var list[list[Int]] =List(list(5,5,5,5,5),
                          list(3,3,3,3,3),
                          list(2,2,2,2,2))
```

Desired Output :

var output= List(10,10,10,10,10)

Comment: What have you tried? BTW that is a **List[Any]** which should be already a code smell. Finally, your expected output doesn't make sense to me. It seems you are trying to model a database as a big list? I would recommend using a more typesafe model.

Comment: hi @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thanks for your reply , I have edited the question . kindly look one more time . are you able to understand my issue ?

Comment: Still your attempt at solving the question is missing.

Comment: @jwvh please check now .i have edited question

Comment: It may be easier to solve the problem if you model it using some **case class** to represent each row, then you can just use `groupMapReduce` over the original list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this a two-dimensional array, and you want to sum columns? It's the only way I can see to get your outcome. It would be clearer if you used a range of numbers, not just 5, 3, 2

Anyway, if I am correct, that doesn't need groupBy

Fixing your syntax errors first:

```
var xs:List[List[Int]] =List(List(5,5,5,5,5),
                             List(3,3,3,3,3),
                             List(2,2,2,2,2))
```

Then it's just

```
xs.transpose.map{_.sum}

// List(10, 10, 10, 10, 10): List[Int]
```